# How do i use the VLC to auto replay as loop?

Tags: linux, logging, vlc, libvlc, vlcj

VLC how can i apply auto loop of the given content while using with options? Following did not work to loop.

```
private void start() {

    frame.setVisible(true);
    String mrl = "file:///home/sun/Downloads/t1.avi";
    // fails
//    String[] options = {
//      "--loops",
//      "--repeat",};

    ///Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -vv qtcapture:// --sout='#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=768,fps=25.0,scale=1}:standard{access=udp,mux=ts{dts-delay=9000},dst=239.0.0.5}'

    //mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
    //String[] options = {"--loops"};
    // no luck fails too
    mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, 
            ":sout ':standard{loop}'");


  }
```

Comment: It should be `--loop`, not `--loops` see http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help

Comment: @eee: tried same not looping with both.

Comment: If you use `VLCJ`, I suggest that you to call `mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `VLCJ`, I suggest that you to call `mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);` It works in my  VLCJ project as follows:

```
mediaPlayer.setRepeat(true);
mediaPlayer.setPlaySubItems(true);
mediaPlayer.playMedia(mrl, options);
```

Tested with with `JRE 1.6 32-bit`:

- `VLCJ 1.2.0` + VLC engine `libVLC 1.1.11` (Windows 32-bit)
- `VLCJ 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT` + nightly build VLC engine `libVLC 2.1.0` (Windows 32-bit)

Comment: tried VLCJ 1.2.0 not working still vlcj, using Fedora/CentOS. (LibVlcFactory.java:106)                 | INFO  | vlc: 1.1.13 The Luggage, changeset exported
vlcj: (LibVlcFactory.java:107)                 | INFO  | libvlc: libvlc.so

Comment: Sorry, I could not check Linux version of libVLC 1.1.13 and how well it works with VLCJ 1.2.0. since I do my work under Windows. Maybe, you can ask VLCJ developer, Mark Lee, about `MediaPlayer.setRepeat()` method since he normally does his work under Linux OS.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you had a typo; [the documented option is "--loop"](http://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_command-line_help).

The following is all that is needed:

```
vlc --loop video.mp4
```

To do this from Java, you could:

```
public class Player {
    public static final void main(String args[]) {
        try { 
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("vlc --loop "+args[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }   
    }   
}
```

and then:

```
java Player filename.mp4
```

Comment: Yes tried: but not working in my above code with :loop or --loop.

Answer (score -4):

In the latest version, no need for complex scripting. 
Click on TOOLS > PREFERENCES. 
Look bottom left of interface, 
"Show settings" radio button should be set to "ALL". 
Look at left Panel, click on "Playlist". 
Check/Tick "Repeat All" CHECKBOX.

Comment: the question concern libvlc API not VLC application itself

Comment: Not VLC GUI app, its about LibVLC